# How to get the value of root element in xml

Tags: c#, xml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to make a Windows RT program and I can't seem to figure out how to get the value of the root element. The xmldocument only contains:

`<double>0.7423</double>`

How would I go about getting the value "0.7422" using c# and window store? Every time I try something it returns a null value.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
            `var getRate = from query in xmlDoc.Descendants("double")
                             select new
                             {
                                 Rate = query.Value
                             };

            foreach (var query in getRate)
            {
                rate = Convert.ToDouble(query.Rate);

            }`
```

I also tried this:

```
`var rate= xmlDoc.Root.Element("double").Value;

 var rate= xmlDoc.Element("double").Value;

 rate = (double)XElement.Load(xmlstream);`
```

But rate always returns a null value.

Comment: `Every time I try something it returns a null value.` can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Please post XML content because the thing which are _not_ working for you works for me.

Comment: Here is the web link where you can find the xml document:

[link](http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=EUR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while but it was simpler than I thought. Here's how I did it:

```
            var xelement = XElement.Parse(outputtext);
            rate = (double)xelement;
```

Thank you everyone for your help/suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string xml = "<double>0.7423</double>";
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var doubleValue = document.Descendants("double").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access root element of document via [Root](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.root.aspx) property:

```
double d = (double)XDocument.Load(path_to_xml).Root;
```

But in this case you even don't need to create document. You can create element:

```
double d = (double)XElement.Load(path_to_xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite obvious:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xml = "<double>0.7423</double>";

        Debug.WriteLine("Method1: {0}", Method1(xml));
        Debug.WriteLine("Method2: {0}", Method2(xml));
        Debug.WriteLine("Method3: {0}", Method3(xml));
    }

    private static double Method1(string xml)
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var doubleStr = xdoc.Root.Value;
        var doubleValue = double.Parse(doubleStr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return doubleValue;
    }

    private static double Method2(string xml)
    {
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
        return double.Parse(xmlDoc.FirstChild.InnerText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    private static double Method3(string xml)
    {
        var doubleStr = xml.Substring(
            xml.IndexOf(">") + 1,
            xml.IndexOf("</") - xml.IndexOf(">") - 1
            );

        return double.Parse(doubleStr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but it's the good way I think

```
XmlDocument doc = new XlmDocument();
doc.Load("path");
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement.InnerText
```